# incompatible phpmailer con ajax

Tags: php, ajax

I am using phpmailer to send an email the function send mail I call it through ajax and htaccess when the function sending the mail should return an answer echo json_encode (true);
but I receive something like that

> responseText:2019-07-30 21:49:58 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP y71sm15279487vsc.19 - gsmtp
> ↵2019-07-30 21:49:58 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO localhost
> ↵2019-07-30 21:49:58 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception; 
function enviarCorreo($para, $contraseña)
  {
require 'views/assets/lib/mailer/vendor/autoload.php';

try {
// Instantiation and passing `true` enables exceptions
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
//Server settings
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;                                       // Enable verbose debug output
$mail->isSMTP();                                            // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host       = 'smtp.gmail.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username   = 'mail@gmail.com';                     // SMTP username
$mail->Password   = '******';                               // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                                  // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port       = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

//Recipients
$mail->setFrom('mail@gmail.com', 'Biomatic');
$mail->addAddress($para);     // Add a recipient


// // Attachments
// $mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
// $mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name

// Content
$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
$mail->Subject = 'Cambio de clave';
$mail->Body    = 'Buen dia  se ha solicitado el cambio de contraseña su nueva contraseña es: <b>' . $contraseña . '</b>';
$mail->AltBody = 'Si no solicito con anterioridad el cambio de contraseña por fabor contacte al administrador de el sitio gracias.';

$mail->send();
echo json_encode(true);
}
```

I need the response text to be true so that the ajax can perform the required actions

Comment: You enabled verbose debug output (`$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;`). Remove it and try again.

Comment: thank you very much my solution helped me totally